# Date Taken for images

Tags: google-drive-api

I am using the Google Drive API in Google Script. I am trying to retrieve the original Date Taken of a photo.

as per the Drive SDK website, this is: `{"imageMediaMetadata": {"date": string}}`. The site says:

> imageMediaMetadata.date = the date and time the photo was taken (EXIF
>   format timestamp).

However, I noticed that if the image has been edited, it will show the date of the modification, rather than the original date taken.

I opened the file via http://regex.info/exif.cgi, and see that indeed there are two dates in the file `EXIF: Date/Time Original & Modify Date`

The API is giving me the Modify Date, rather than Date/Time Original

How do I get the original Date Taken?

Answer (score 0):

The EXIF data is not involved in the creation and modified dates returned by the Drive API and merely exposed as additional metadata. This is because the same fields need to be filled for files with no EXIF data (i.e. all non-images).

I agree it would be pretty cool to expose that data, but it is not really reliable for the sake of Drive.

Comment: Ali, for images (only) on Drive the API is returning "imageMediaMetadata", which contains all sorts of metadata, like "cameraMake", "cameraModel", "exposureTime",  "aperture", "flashUsed", etc, etc (see https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files). Note: This metadata is not populated for non-images. It also returns imageMediaMetadata.date, which is supposed to be the date taken. Unfortunately, it isn't, as explained in my post. To me, this just seems like a defect/shortcoming in the API itself, don't you think?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the date string provided in {"imageMediaMetadata": {"date": string}} appears to be coming from the Exif/Image/DateTime field.  This field does indeed get changed when the image is re-saved (e.g. when the image is rotated in the Windows Image Viewer).  As there's no other date field currently in the Drive extended API, a workaround may be to use an Exif editor to reset DateTime equal to DateTimeOriginal for modified images.